# Can't Change Icons Color After Focusing Div

Tags: html, css

I am quite "*newbie*" on css and trying to change the color of `FontAwesome` icon when the main div is focused. I have tried several methods, tried to change its color using div's `id` or `class` on **focus** but none worked.

I have also tried `active` and `hover` state just to test, none worked aswell.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
   <label for="username" class="..">User Field <span class="..">*</span></label>
   <div id="test" class="has-feedback">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" vk_1e5ee="subscribed">
      <span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.form-control-feedback {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 34px;
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.form-control:focus .form-control-feedback:focus  {
  color:red;
}

/*
#test:focus span .fa {
  color:red;
}*/
```

**JSFiddle Link:** http://jsfiddle.net/xh8wsr5g/2/

I can change the color of main div when focused but cannot change the icon. What would you suggest me to do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to use the sibling selector.

Your font-awesome span is a sibling of textbox so following one is wont work

```
.form-control:focus  {
  color:red;
}
```

Instead of it you have to use following code

```
.form-control:focus + .form-control-feedback {
  color:red;
}
```

See fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/xh8wsr5g/1/

So whenever the textbox is in focus the font-awesome span color will be red.

See this link for imformation about sibling selector 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Comment: Thank you, I thought I was able to use it like `.form-control:focus .form-control-feedback:focus`. Since it didn't worked for both I tried to use sibling selector via `id` but that didn't worked either, until your solution.

Comment: @MesutK .form-control:focus .form-control-feedback:focus - the space means that you are targetting .form-control-feedback WITHIN .form-control. You can either use + (adjacent) like Kaushal has above, or use a comma.

Answer (score 1):

just add this code:

```
// to make the text color change
.form-control:focus  {
  color:red;
}

// to make the icon color change
.form-control:focus + .form-control-feedback {
  color:red;
}
```

you can try this http://jsfiddle.net/xh8wsr5g/3/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot accomplish this with css alone, `.form-control-feedback` is not a child of `.form-control`. Therefore there will be no element accessible through `.form-control:focus .form-control-feedback:focus`, try using jquery to change the color:

```
$('.form-control').focus(function(){
    $('.form-control-feedback').css('color','red');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works but not completely, after getting out of `focus` the color stays `red` again. I could change it with another line of code but sibling method seems a lot useful in this case.

Comment: jQuery solution to a CCS problem seems a little OTT.

Comment: Yeah, for changing back should be blur, but anyways no problem.